# SMS sent from twilo blocked by tmobile I believe

Tags: sms, twilio

So to help debug we even take it out of our code and put it on twilio portal that lets us test the API. When I send to most of our group everyone gets the text message, but when we send to someone with tmobile, the message says it's delivered on twilio logs, but the person never gets it.

If we test and send him an 'Hello world' message, he gets it, but when we test with out SMS
'XXXXXX wants to make plans with you on the HotSauce App. :tada::hot_pepper:
Get the app now to join in on the action. https://rts2t.app.goo.gl/FGYB'

The message doesn't get delivered. Maybe there's a whitelist for Tmobile we can get on?
FYI, we have a USA number and this is a USA person and we are on the paid version, not trial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue working on another app, and unfortunately I do not think there's a conclusive single answer. Carriers intentionally keep their spam filtering techniques secret so that they cannot be gamed. From [Twilio's support page on the topic](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181848-How-Does-Carrier-Filtering-Work-):

> There is no standard practice for carrier filtering across all carriers. For some, filtering can range from a simple static list of prohibited terms to advanced machine learning systems that work in real time. Regardless of the system, carriers keep their filtering systems closely guarded secrets. In turn, Twilio cannot say definitively how these systems work or why a particular message was filtered.

Note that not all carriers report errors to Twilio, so some messages may appear to go through even though they were not delivered. You may or may not see error 30007 in the Twilio console when a message is blocked.

I don't believe any type of universal white-list exists, and once a number has been black-listed by a carrier there is no easy process to have it white-listed. However, [short-code](https://www.twilio.com/sms/short-codes) numbers are generally less prone to getting spam filtered (though they are more expensive).

While there isn't any one thing you can do to guarantee delivery, there are several things you can try:

- Make the language of the text message more conversational as opposed to promotional
- Don't obscure the url with a link shortener
- Don't over-use a single number by implementing something like Twilio co-pilot
- Include clear opt-out instructions